# Count number of results from MYSQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm wondering the right way to count the number of results returned from mysql.

This is my code for grabbing the data from my table.

```
$bids = $this->db->query("SELECT bidID,listingID, listing_title, bid_date, username, vintage, starting_, bin,
amount, sold, sold_date, bid_type 
FROM bids

JOIN listings ON listingID = bid_listing
JOIN users ON list_uID = userID

ORDER BY bidID DESC");

$bids = $bids->result();
$data['bids'] = $bids;
```

I am then running a foreach to print the data. For example :

```
  <?$i = "0"; foreach ($bids as $l): ?> <? echo $l->listing_title;?>
```

I would then like to add the number of bids / results after the listing title.

Thanks

Comment: `count($bids)` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: @MajidFouladpour It doesn't look like he's using `mysqli`. It doesn't have a `result()` method.

Comment: @Barmar, what is `$bids = $bids->result();` then?

Comment: Looks like CodeIgniter.

Comment: What is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using codeigniter active record

```
public function count() {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('bids');
  $this->db->join('listings', 'listings.listingID = bids.bid_listing', 'LEFT');
  $this->db->join('users', 'users.userID = listings.list_uID', 'LEFT');
  $query = $this->db->get();

  return $query->num_rows();
}

echo $this->count();
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem :

```
$bids = $this->db->query("SELECT bidID,listingID, listing_title, bid_date, username, vintage, starting_, bin,
amount, sold, sold_date, bid_type 
FROM bids

JOIN listings ON listingID = bid_listing
JOIN users ON list_uID = userID

ORDER BY bidID DESC");

$bids = $bids->result();
$no_0f_bids = $bids->num_rows();
$data['bids'] = $bids;
$data['no_0f_bids'] = $no_0f_bids;
```

Then you can print no of bids in view file.

```
<?php  
echo "No of Bids : ".$no_0f_bids;
foreach ($bids as $l):
    echo $l->listing_title;
endforeach;
?>
```

and you can visit this link for [Generating codeigniter  Query Results.](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

I hope it will help.

Comment: I originally tried something similar, I just tested yours and I'm getting the same error : Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$bids = $this->db->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS bidID,listingID, listing_title, bid_date, username, vintage, starting_, bin, amount, sold, sold_date, bid_type FROM bids JOIN listings ON listingID = bid_listing JOIN users ON list_uID = userID ORDER BY bidID DESC");

$total = $this->db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total");
$data['bids'] = $bids->result();
$data['bids_total'] = $total->row()->total;
```

Or

```
$bids = $this->db->query("SELECT  bidID,listingID, listing_title, bid_date, username, vintage, starting_, bin, amount, sold, sold_date, bid_type FROM bids JOIN listings ON listingID = bid_listing JOIN users ON list_uID = userID ORDER BY bidID DESC");

$data['bids'] = $bids->result();
$data['bids_total'] = $bids->num_rows();
```

Or

```
$data['bids_total'] = count($data['bids']);
```

Comment: How would I echo the above?

Comment: You pass data array to view just use echo $bids_total;

Comment: Ok this is working!

However 

ORDER BY bidID DESC");


Instead of ORDER BY bidID - how can I order by the one with the most bids? from bids table

Answer (score 0):

You should have `$db->RecordCount()`
This function will be return count which you want.